# How to generate C.UTF-8 locale in MacOS to use Postgresql

Tags: locale, macos

I want to use `C.UTF-8` locale in MacOS(10.15.3) that doesn't exist by default.
And there is no `locale-gen` command in Mac.

How can I create a locale in MacOS?

I only use the locale for Postgresql DB.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't using Debian Linux.  `locale-gen` is a Debian tool, a shell script that wraps around the actual standard tool for creating locales.  This tool is `localedef`, as described in the *Single Unix Specification* and as available on MacOS.

It takes a locale *source file* and a character map file as input.  The *SUS* specifies the formats for both, and according to the Apache C++ manual for *its own* `localedef` it used to be the case (but apparently no longer) that one could download locale source files from The Open Group.

Note that one reported way to configure `C.UTF-8` on MacOS is to use the C locale and overlay the UTF-8 locale, that MacOS has, just for character typing, i.e.

```
export LANG=C LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
```

This is [reportedly what MacOS terminal emulators set up in their child process environments](https://bugs.python.org/issue18378#msg215215).  It used to be how things worked on FreeBSD, too.  (Setting a *.UTF-8 locale for `LANG` effecively did the same thing, thanks to the `LC_CTYPE` locale file being a symbolic link to `../UTF-8/LC_CTYPE` in those locales.)

Note that the 4.4BSD `mklocale` tool is *not* for creating locales.  It is for specifically creating the character type portions of locales.

## Further reading

- `man localedef`
- [`localedef`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/localedef.html).  *The Open Group Base Specifications*.   IEEE Std 1003.1-2017.
- `localedef`. *Apache C++ Standard Library Reference Guide*.  apache.org.