# locale of .utf8 or .UTF-8?

Tags: debian, docker, locale

Of the *same* Debian 11 bullseye, I get *different* `locale` for `C`: `.utf8` and `.UTF-8`:

My machine:

```bash
$ locale -a
C
C.utf8
POSIX
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Yet, in its docker container, I got:

```bash
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

I'm wondering where the difference is coming from and how to get them the same.

My bullseye docker container is only built 2 weeks ago:

```bash
$ docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
. . .
debian         latest    54e726b437fb   2 weeks ago   124MB
```

Comment: It is implementation-dependent: [Is the \`utf8\` in \`en\_US.utf8\` a canonical character set?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605770/is-the-utf8-in-en-us-utf8-a-canonical-character-set) (so much for standards).